# Grid thumbnails with preview on top on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am making a simple website in Bootstrap for my client. On one of the web pages he wants a gallery with thumbnails, and on clicking them the preview should expand to fit the full width of the page right above the row having thumbnails.

I tried finding suitable plugins, but that almost went in vain. I found something working but the preview shows below the row always.

Here's how it looks right now

[image]

The row of thumbnails is the first thing on the webpage after the navigation bar, so a preview would have to shift the row below and take the space above.

Please guide me how to make this thing.

Comment: Are you saying that the page has the thumbnail row down to far to see on the page load? and you want the thumb naill row to be in perfect view in the bottom of the slide show?

Comment: Please add a snippet or fiddle to your question so it will easier for us to answer this.